# How sub is getting executed?

Tags: python

How is `sub` printing 24 because `i` will get `['24']` and `sub` should only run once? and I am totally confused how `sub` can print integer `24` because inner for loop will run only once.

```py
l1=[['24']]
for i in l1:
    print(i)
    for sub in i:
        print(sub)
```

output is:

```
['24']
24
```

Comment: IndentationError ...

Comment: It doesn't print integer, try `print(type(sub))`, you should get `<class 'str'>`. It just prints without quotes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging Might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not understand your output, add more prints (and/or data) to it until you do:

```
l1=[['24',"Y"],"X"]
for i in l1:                   # iterates all elements of the outer list
    print("i is:",i, type(i))
    for sub in i:              # iterates all elements of the inner list
        print("sub is:",sub, type(sub))
        for s in sub:          # iterates the single characters of your string
            print("s is:",s,type(s))
```

Output (formatted):

```
i is: ['24', 'Y'] <class 'list'>
    sub is: 24 <class 'str'>
        s is: 2 <class 'str'>
        s is: 4 <class 'str'>
    sub is: Y <class 'str'>
        s is: Y <class 'str'>
i is: X <class 'str'>
    sub is: X <class 'str'>
        s is: X <class 'str'>
```

See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)